# Disk ceramic capacitor reading

Tags: capacitor

I'm struggling to decide if this capacitor is 150pF or 68pF (and in the latter case, what does the `151K` stand for?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *what does the 151\$\color{red}{K}\$ stand for?*

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Capacitor).

K means 10 % tolerance. The 151 part usually means 15 with 1 zero = 150 pF.

153J would be 15000 pF or a 15 nF 5% capacitor.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, what does the `68` at the end stands for?

Comment: I have no idea unfortunately - you do see a lot of "extra" info printed on some disc capacitors and most of it can be figured out but, this I can't. I'm certain as I can be that it isn't the 68 pF value.